# How to modify JSON-LD in the header after page load, asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json-ld, helmet.js

At the beginning of page load I added JSON-LD data to the header:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context":"http://schema.org",
      ...
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Later I get some extra asynchronous data that I want to add as well, since [Google is able to crawl it](https://centrical.com/test/google-json-ld-and-javascript-crawling-and-indexing-test.html).

Wondering how may I change the existing JSON-LD data in header?

Comment: You could give the script tag an id or some identification attribute at render time and replace it with whole new script tag once you have the new data.

Comment: That works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`react-helmet`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) and render your schema script:

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

const schema = {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Doe"
    ...
}

<Helmet>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
       {JSON.stringify(schema)}
    </script>
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Hi @Przemysław, while helmet does add things to the header with rendering of a component, I have yet to see if there's any possibility, or a convenient way, of header modification with Helmet after the page is fully loaded. Say you get some reviews asynchronously after the component is rendered, how would you add them to the json-ld?

Comment: You should be able to just re-render the `Helmet` after state change and the schema will be updated. You can use regular `setState` or Redux for that. 
I have just checked it in my own app and that is working as intended.